# Sticky Footer with Bootstrap - width issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on getting a Responsive Variable height sticky footer. I am using `Twitter Bootstrap` with following page template. I have added CSS to have a sticky footer. I am getting desired result as far as height of the page is concerned. But the width of the page is reduced in spite of using class `container-fluid`. I have also tried adding same class to header/footer. I can not see Width set for any of the body, header, footer, #wrapper when I check for it in Firebug computed styles.

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}

body {
  display: table;
}
header, #wrapper, footer{
  display: table-row;
}
#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
}
footer {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</header>
<div id="wrapper" class="container-fluid">
</div>
<footer class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Set `.navbar margin-bottom:0`. This adjust footer according to the height of `wrapper` or content present between those 2 `navbar`.

```css
#wrapper{
  height:500px;
}
.navbar{
  margin-bottom:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <nav class ="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class ="container-fluid"></div>
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
</div>

<footer>
 <nav class ="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class ="container-fluid"></div>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: I do not want it fixed at bottom if page height goes beyond viewport height. It should be pushed to bottom when page height is smaller than viewport height.

Comment: @bvnbhati Why did you set your body display:table.

Comment: This is the only way to get the footer stick to bottom if it has variable height. See this- http://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/

Comment: Please note @frnt -I have achieved objective of height using styles I have shown. Also, I can not set fixed height for wrapper as it will vary from page to page on my application. My problem is width of page is reduced, although I am using full width classes of Bootstrap.